# How reliable is the "host" in an incoming HTTPS request?

Tags: security, http-headers

I'm trying to understand what level of confidence I can have when my API which lives at `api.foo.com` receives a POST request from a page that has `foo.com` specified as its *host* value in the header.

Specifically - is this something that can be faked (maybe even is somehow easy to fake?) or is it difficult (impossible?) for someone to send something to `api.foo.com` from some entirely alternate location and spoof in the header that the host is `foo.com`?

If it's not difficult or impossible then what's the industry standard mechanism for verifying that the request is coming from a trusted place?

Answer (score 3):

The `Host` header is part of the HTTP request that specifies which virtual host on the web server the request is made to.

It has nothing to do with the source of the request. Anyone can make a HTTP / HTTPS request to your web server, and specify `google.com` in the `Host` header. Then it is up to your web server to decide what it wants to do with the request.

Browsers typically add HTTP `Referer` header to requests, which indicates what is the source page that provided the URL for this request. However, `Referer` field is also untrusted user input, and it can be easily faked.

An example:

User is visitiing `http://www.example.com/example` website, which has a hyperlink to `http://www.example.org`. User clicks on the link. User's browser sends the request to IP address of `www.example.org`, with the following HTTP headers:

```
Host: www.example.org
Referer: http://www.example.com/example
```

Recently browsers have started to strip `Referer` header contents so that it contains only the root URL: `http://www.example.com`, when making cross-domain requests.

Overall, you cannot trust any HTTP request header to contain exactly the data you expect, since it is untrusted user input.

Answer (score 2):

The Host: request header ([RFC 7230 § 5.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-5.4)) is *untrusted user input*. It is supplied by the user agent to indicate the (virtual) host that the HTTP request pertains to. Any malicious user agent can connect to your server and make a request with an invalid Host: header.

You are meant to validate that the content of the Host: header corresponds to your actual hostname before processing the request. Normally the web server (nginx, Apache, etc.) takes care of this for you and then passes the request to your app. But if you expose the app directly to the Internet, not behind a regular web server, then you must validate it yourself.

Comment: wait - so - the webserver *can validate that the call is indeed coming from foo.com and not from something that stuck foo.com into the header? Do you know where I can read about how this works and how reliable this is? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: This is one of the most basic functions of the web server. Have you set one up before? See for example https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: "can validate that the call is indeed coming from foo.com and not from something that stuck foo.com into the header"  I believe the host is not where it is *from* it is where it is *to*... in other words, the remote request is asking for foo.com which should be one of your host aliases (but might not be).